# Signed routes en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, rutas, middleware

Estoy tratando de utilizar rutas firmadas dentro de laravel utilizando el middleware signed, en donde aplique este middleware en una de mis rutas de mi archivo web.php

`Route::view('/inicio',"inicio")->middleware('auth','signed')->name('inicio');`

pero al momento de ingresar a esta ruta, me marca el error **403: invalid signature**

no se si me falta alguna configuracion extra, o mandar de alguna forma esa peticion de firma dentro de mis vistas o de mis controladores.

Comment: Y le estas pasando la firma a esa ruta?

Comment: ya lo solucione, en un momento actualizo mi respuesta